# transpose of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. How would you define $A^{Tr}$, the transpose of $A$ with respect to fixed but arbitrary orthonormal basis of $A$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem which implies the existence and uniqueness of the adjoint of an operator.

Comment: are the adjoint of an operator and the transpose of an operator the same thing?

Comment: I think so. In fact we usually call the "transpose" adjoint in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: but in a finite Hilbert space H, are the transpose of an operator A on H different from the adjoin of an operator on H?

Comment: nope. They are the same thing regardless of the dimensionality. What I mean is in infinite dimensional spaces people usually use a different terminology i.e. Adjoint than what they use in finite dimensional spaces i.e. Transposé.

Comment: i was a little bit confused. some uses different symbols and notations. For the adjoint of an operator A, they use A* and for the transpose of an operator, they use $A^{Tr}$.

Comment: In the usual terminology, *matrices* have a transpose and *operators* have an adjoint.  It is somewhat unusual to talk about the adjoint of a matrix.  It is extremely unusual to talk about the transpose of an operator.

Comment: a matrix has a transpose and also has an adjoint, but the two are different. On the other hand, for an operator on a Hilbert space H, yes it has an adjoint. My question is this: does it have a transpose with respect to a fixed but arbitrary orthonormal basis of H?

Comment: @JayBuscano So for you, the "adjoint" of a matrix with complex entries is the conjugate-transpose, and the "transpose" of such a matrix is just the transpose without taking the conjugate.  Is that right?  Are these the ideas that you're trying to extend to arbitrary Hilbert spaces?

Comment: actually what i am looking for right now is the formal definition of a transpose of a linear operator (if there is). I've read an article about linear preservers and the author used the notation $A^{Tr}$ to denote the transpose of an operator with respect to a fixed but arbitrary orthonormal basis of $H$. I dont know if the transpose $A^{Tr}$ that he's talkin' about is actually an adjoint of an operator $A$, but he just simply used different terminology. I'm a bit confused. Can you please help me on this?